# Validate phone number on client via jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, input, numeric

I want to validate input in form as well as example
http://prgassist.blogspot.ru/2011/04/jquery-plugin-autonumeric.html

My code

```
<input id="groupingNumber" />

$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#groupingNumber').autoNumeric({aSep:',', aNeg:'', mDec:0, mNum:10}); 

});
```

My task is - user can input only digits and can't input letters.
Input contains digits in special format (as example - phone number).

But my example doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console? Maybe jQuery or the libraries .js file isn't loaded

Comment: It worked for me. If the scripts is not loaded, then download it to your local machine and refer it from there.